# how to import video from iphone with no time duration

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, video, uiimagepickercontroller

can any one help me please
i just want to pick video from iphone which already recorded with help of uiimagepicker controller.
i want to copy my apps document directory.
---------------------------------- prashant

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure of what you mean with no time duration. But you can do the copying/moving in the `UIImagePickerDelegate` method.

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSURL *movieURL = (NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSURL *saveURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"movie.mov"]];

    NSError *error;
    if (!([[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtURL:movieURL toURL:saveURL error:&error])) {
        NSLog(@"Error saving: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```